Zongshen Scooter 150cc
I have a 150cc scooter with a 2 month old battery, I have a lot of new parts installed also. The scooter was driving fine but recently it does not want to start with the button, it just swings, then I have to kick it and when it starts I would switch it off and then start it using the button and it would work, leave it standing for about 4 hours and I'll have to kick start it first again... Any idea what the problem could be?
